# Want to strip a part in a string with regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express, datastore

I want to strip the follwing part :

```
, Symbol(KEY): {"kind": "Quote", "namespace": undefined, "path": ["Quote", undefined]}}
```

from this json response coming from a get query (datastore):

```
{
  "aboutYourself": {
    "creditFile": true,
    "dateOfBirth": {
      "date": {
        "day": 3,
        "month": 5,
        "year": 1992
      }
    },
  Symbol(KEY): {
    "kind": "Quote",
    "namespace": undefined,
    "path": [
      "Quote",
      undefined
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried many regex but it doesn't work, my regex expertise is really low. thank you

Comment: What you want is quite weird. May I know what are you trying to do logically?

Comment: Hi it's because for my test i need to compare what i send to datastore, to what i query , so the issue is this part which is added by datastore (gcp). so to compare, i need them to be the same

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `/(Symbol\([^)]*\):\s*\{(?:[^}]*[\n\r\s])*})/` is the regex that you'll want for this.

After turning your data into a string, you'll be able to match using that regex to get the Symbol and everything inside it.

It won't, however, be able to get the comma before, or the extra `}` close brace, but other than that, it doesn't stray from the requirements

```js
let data = `{
  "aboutYourself": {
    "creditFile": true,
    "dateOfBirth": {
      "date": {
        "day": 3,
        "month": 5,
        "year": 1992
      }
    },
  Symbol(KEY): {
    "kind": "Quote",
    "namespace": undefined,
    "path": [
      "Quote",
      undefined
    ]
  }
};`

let regex = /(Symbol\([^)]*\):\s*\{(?:[^}]*[\n\r\s])*})/;

console.log(regex.exec(data)[0]);
```

After that, it's just a case of doing a replace with the result of the match for a space, and job's a good'n

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest capturing the parts before and after the section you want stripped.  A pattern such as

```
^(.*), Symbol(KEY): {"kind": "Quote", "namespace": undefined, "path": ["Quote", undefined]}}(.*)$
```

should do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to strip it:
Just a JSON.Stringify  did the trick, because it strips what is not part of the json response.